# git cherry-pick --continue, '--no-edit' option?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I'm writing a script for migrating git repos. On cherry-pick conflicts I run

```
git add .
git cherry-pick --continue
```

This brings up vim, prompting me to save the commit message and freezes the script. I am looking for a command-line option like `--no-edit` or `--porcelain` to get around this.

Ugly terminal hacks might be welcomed as well ;)

Comment: Well I was not clear with claims you posted so I run a test and found that 'git cherry-pick --continue' freezes until merge conflicts are resolved. So how do you resolve them ?

Comment: I resolve the conflicts with `git add .` in the project root. I want to accept all changes, then run `git cherry-pick --continue`.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren I had the same problem with `git rebase`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As [Zildyan said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40679209/1256452), you will need to *resolve* all the conflicts before doing `git add`.  Therefore, you *should not* make this fully automated.

That said, to skip editing the commit *message*, you can simply set your editor to a command that does nothing and reports success.  The ideal one on Unix-like systems is the `true` command.  Hence:

```
git -c core.editor=true cherry-pick --continue
```

will do the trick.  (You can also use any of the environment variables `GIT_EDITOR`, `VISUAL`, or `EDITOR`; and in fact, if any of those are set, you *must* use them rather than `core.editor` since the sequence is: use `$GIT_EDITOR` if that is set; else use `$VISUAL` if that is set; else use `$EDITOR` if that is set; else use `core.editor` if that is set; else use whatever is built in to this version of Git.)

Comment: I prefer the fits option (using `-c`) because there are no side effects. In addition, it can easily be turned into an alias.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss: note that you can use a shell alias to set `GIT_EDITOR`, e.g., `alias foo='GIT_EDITOR=true git cherry-pick --continue'` in bash, or via a Git alias that uses `!` to invoke the shell. However, if `-c core.editor=true` suffices, that's fine too.

Comment: this tricks also works fine in an interactive rebase: `git -c core.editor=true rebase --continue`

Comment: I was using Git in Termux via Android tablet while on vacation.  Ran into this problem and was very frustrated for about 5 minutes until finding this answer.

Comment: @silencedogood: I know nothing of Termux but it's handy to learn to use old-style "line editors" like `ed` and `ex`...

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
git cherry-pick <sha1> --no-commit
```

after resolving conflict you can commit it from script.

Ofcourse you can set cherry-pick strategy-options to automatically resolve conflicts by accepting code from ours/theirs

Without that you'll get standard git markup of conflict

```
+<<<<<<< HEAD
         some code
+||||||| parent of 4d64ec6... test commit
+        first version code
+=======
+        second version code
+>>>>>>> 4d64ec6... test commit
```

Answer (score 1):

From [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40687125/6309):

```
git -c core.editor=true cherry-pick --continue
```

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), tihs is no longer needed.

`git cherry-pick`/`revert` with or without `--[no-]edit` did not spawn the editor as expected (e.g. "`revert --no-edit`" after a conflict still asked to edit the message), which has been corrected with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

See [commit 39edfd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39edfd5cbc4d168db19ec1bc867d78ec7211ec39) (31 Mar 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 82fd285](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82fd285e4606b941bd2bf79be700fb0371599c18), 08 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39edfd5cbc4d168db19ec1bc867d78ec7211ec39): fix edit handling for cherry-pick and revert messages
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Renato Botelho</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> `save_opts()` should save any non-default values.
> It was intended to do this, but since most options in struct `replay_opts` default to 0, it only saved non-zero values.
> Unfortunately, this does not always work for options.edit.
> Roughly speaking, options.edit had a default value of 0 for cherry-pick but a default value of 1 for revert.
> Make `save_opts()` record a value whenever it differs from the default.
>
> `options.edit` was also overly simplistic; we had more than two cases.
> The behavior that previously existed was as follows:
>
> ```
> Non-conflict commits    Right after Conflict
> Edit iff isatty(0)      Edit (ignore isatty(0))
> No edit                 See above
> Edit (ignore isatty(0)) See above
> (*)                     See above
>
> (*) Before stopping for conflicts, No edit is the behavior.  After
>     stopping for conflicts, the --no-edit flag is not saved so see
>     the first two rows.
> ```
>
> However, the expected behavior is:
>
> ```
> Non-conflict commits    Right after Conflict
> Edit iff isatty(0)      Edit iff isatty(0)
> No edit                 Edit iff isatty(0)
> Edit (ignore isatty(0)) Edit (ignore isatty(0))
> No edit                 No edit
> ```
>
> In order to get the expected behavior, we need to change options.edit to a tri-state: unspecified, false, or true.
>
> - When specified, we follow what it says.
> - When unspecified, we need to check whether the current commit being created is resolving a conflict as well as consulting options.action and `isatty(0)`.
>   While at it, add a `should_edit()` utility function that compresses `options.edit` down to a boolean based on the additional information for the non-conflict case.
>
> `continue_single_pick()` is the function responsible for resuming after conflict cases, regardless of whether there is one commit being picked or many.
> Make this function stop assuming edit behavior in all cases, so that it can correctly handle `!isatty(0)` and specific requests to not edit the commit message.

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2024, the command which you mentioned in your question works as intended:

```bash
git cherry-pick --continue --no-edit
```

This was mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67046022/376454). Be wary though that [`rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45783848/376454) needs a different approach:

```bash
git -c core.editor=true rebase --continue
```